# How to save one click if key is pressed?

Tags: c#, xna

When I hold the key <kbd>A</kbd>, bears explode **all the time**.

What I want, is when I click **once** explode only **one**, and wait for another press to explode another one.

```
        KeyboardState board = Keyboard.GetState();
        int newRandomX = rand.Next(800);
        int newRandomY = rand.Next(600);
        float newVelocityX = rand.Next(-5,5);
        float newVelocityY = rand.Next(-5,5);
        Vector2 myVector = new Vector2(newVelocityX, newVelocityY);
        if (bear0.Active && board.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            bear0.Active = false;
            boom.Play(bear0.DrawRectangle.Center.X, bear0.DrawRectangle.Center.Y);
        }
        else if (bear1.Active && board.IsKeyDown(Keys.B) && !oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.B))
        {
            bear1.Active = false;
            boom.Play(bear1.DrawRectangle.Center.X, bear1.DrawRectangle.Center.Y);
        }
        else if (!bear1.Active)
        {
            bear1 = new TeddyBear(Content, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "teddybear1", newRandomX, newRandomY, myVector);
        }
        else if (!bear0.Active)
        {
            bear0 = new TeddyBear(Content, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "teddybear0", newRandomX, newRandomY, myVector);
        }
        board = oldState;
        bear0.Update();
        bear1.Update();
        boom.Update(gameTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convention in XNA keyboard and button handling is to maintain a copy of the old `KeyboardState` and compare it to the current state.  You determine when the key is first pressed by testing if the key is currently down but checking that the **prior state** indicated that the key **was not down**.

MSDN example:

> Compare the values in your **newState** object to the values in the **oldState** object.
>   Keys pressed in the **newState** object that were not pressed in the **oldState** object were pressed during this frame. Conversely, keys pressed in the **oldState** object that are not pressed in the **newState** object were released during this frame.

```
    private void UpdateInput()
    {
        KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();

        // Is the SPACE key down?
        if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            // If not down last update, key has just been pressed.
            if (!oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
            {
                backColor = 
                    new Color(backColor.R, backColor.G, (byte)~backColor.B);
            }
        }
        else if (oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            // Key was down last update, but not down now, so
            // it has just been released.
        }

        // Update saved state.
        oldState = newState;
    }
```

Change your code from:

```
    if (bear0.Active && board.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
    {
        bear0.Active = false;
        boom.Play(bear0.DrawRectangle.Center.X, bear0.DrawRectangle.Center.Y);
    }
```

...to:

```
    if (bear0.Active && board.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) && !oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) )
    {
        bear0.Active = false;
        boom.Play(bear0.DrawRectangle.Center.X, bear0.DrawRectangle.Center.Y);
    }
```

...is better than looking at the bear's state `bear0.Active` because the frame after you explode the bear you constuct a new one:

```
    else if (!bear0.Active)
    {
        bear0 = new TeddyBear(Content, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "teddybear0", newRandomX, newRandomY, myVector);
    }
```

...which will explode in the next frame during your next `if (bear0.Active && board.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)`

### Tell Me More

- [Detecting a Key Press (Windows, Windows Phone, Xbox 360)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203902.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)