# XNA - Text not being drawn

Tags: c#, xna, drawing

I have some pause menu text, when I pause the game I want it to display. It's not displaying and I am not entirely sure why, which is why I have posted this question. Here is my code.

```
            if (!paused)
        {
            if (AccessMGame || AccessCampaign)
            {
                PlayerStatus.Update();
                EntityManager.Update();
                EnemySpawner.Update();
                ParticleManager.Update();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pauseMenuGameState = true;
        }
```

This code dictates whether the game is paused, if the game is not paused, update the game, if it is set the `pauseMenuGameState` to true. Here is the code which I am trying to display my text with.

```
if (pauseMenuGameState == true)
        {
            Color color2 = Color.White;
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Texture, BlendState.Additive);
            DrawCenterAlignedString("Paused", ScreenSize.Y / 2 - 100, color2);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
```

And finally, the `DrawCenterAlignedString` function.

```
public void DrawCenterAlignedString(string text, float y, Color color)
    {
        var textWidth = Art.Font.MeasureString(text).X;
        spriteBatch.DrawString(Art.Font, text, new Vector2(ScreenSize.X / 2 - textWidth + textWidth / 2, y), color);

    }
```

Note: The decleration of the paused variable is `public static bool paused = false;` and the declaration of the  pause menu game state variable is `public static bool pauseMenuGameState;` I have debugged my program to find out that the code is being reached, and for some reason is not drawing the text.

I think these methods are what is causing the problems.

```
private static bool _isPaused = false;

    public static void pauseMenu()
    {
        if (Input.WasKeyPressed(Keys.P))
        {
            _isPaused = true;
            GameRoot.paused = !GameRoot.paused;
        }
    }

    public static bool isPaused()
    {
        return _isPaused;
    }
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `pauseMenu()` where it is not quite correct.  _[Convention in XNA keyboard and button handling is to maintain a copy of the old KeyboardState and compare it to the current state. You determine when the key is first pressed by testing if the key is currently down but checking that the prior state indicated that the key was not down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324417/how-to-save-one-click-if-key-is-pressed)_

Answer (score 0):

According to [the MSDN description of SpriteBatch.DrawString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433981.aspx) I see no error. Did you check that the code is beeing reached, and that the calculated width of the string is correct? You should log all the paramaters to the console for debugging. You should also check if [this basic example from the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447673.aspx) works for you.

Comment: After debugging my program, I found out that the code is being reached and the console says the sprite has been drawn.

Comment: Another shot would be to check the spriteBatch.Begin() command, especially the SpriteSortMode. In the MSDN example, sprireBatch.Begin() is called without arguments. (Though I can understand that you want it atleast to be additive, sothat it gets drawn over the existing screen.). Another source of error could be that the Text is indeed being drawn, but beeing invisible due to color or size. Check the Art.Font properties to check for any mistakes there.

Comment: I have found out that there is no problems with drawing the text, but the pauseMenu and isPaused functions are causing problems in my update method. When I am not calling them, the game updates 100% of the time, however the draw function always updates.